# Selenium IDE - how to get result of verifyNotText and do the right action

Tags: selenium, ide, command

I'm using Selenium IDE, and I have to use only that tool.
I have this scenario: I've the check if my mailbox it contains message or not. 
The only way is to check if there is a certain string on the page.

I've applied this

```
Command: verifyNotText
Target: //form[@id='messages']/table/tbody/tr/td[5]
Value: "on behalf of:.*"
```

How can I check the result of this command?
I mean: if the result is true the test will proceed with a list of commands,
instead it should execute other commands.

I was thinking to use something like:

```
Command: gotoif 
Target:  previous command
Value:   goAhead
```

Have you any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `storeTextPresent`. If you want to use `gotoIf` function, you need a variable.

```
storeTextPresent on behalf of:.* text //text is a variable name
gotoIf ${text}==on behalf of:.* Yes //Yes and No are labels
gotoIf ${text}!=on behalf of:.* No
label Yes 
//instructions if text present equals "on behalf of:.*"
goto End
label No
//instructions if text present not equals "on behalf of:.*"
```

Another useful thing might be using `goto` function. You can "drive" your test with this function, if you want to jump to particular step.
Example:

```
goto End //jump to label End
label End
```

Hope it helps!
If anything is unclear, please, leave a comment